# How to get text from a Selected Index c#

Tags: c#, text, indexing, listbox, selectedindex

Once the country has been located by the search show the integer and the names of the two countries immediately before that country on the list. I know how to get the index value of the selected country, but i don't know how to get the text that it is highlighting.

e.g Australia has an index of 10. I can get the index value using:

```
int f = lbxcombo.SelectedIndex;
```

where f is the index value. But I can't get the text that the index represents (Australia).

Comment: Did you try GetItemText()?

Comment: You got any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lbxcombo.Items[index]` will return the text at the index

in your case use

```
int f = lbxcombo.SelectedIndex;

string text=lbxcombo.Items[f].ToString()
```

to get australia

Answer (score 2):

Use `GetItemText` and [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx):

```
string foo = lbxcombo.GetItemText(lbxcombo.SelectedItem);
```

Or use the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx) property:

```
string foo = lbxcombo.Text;
```

Comment: What if I needed to display the text on the indexes before the selected index?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? `Display the text on the indexes`? Are you trying to retrieve the text at a given index? Or the selected item in the combobox?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
String country = lbxcombo.SelectedItem.Text;
```

OR

```
Items[lbxcombo.SelectedIndex].Text
```

Comment: C# is a case sensitive language. `lbxcombo.selecteditem.text` wont compile

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you only need to use the text property for this :-

```
string Foo = lbxcombo.text;
```